# Is SOCKS proxy lest secure than VPN? How?

Tags: vpn, proxy

In what circumstances a SOCKS proxy is vulnerable and a VPN is not?

Comment: Are you talking about a local SOCKS proxy which then opens an encrypted tunnel to a remote server (that's how Tor works), or a remote SOCKS proxy?

Comment: A good middle-ground between SOCKS and VPN would be a **HTTPS proxy**. I have Squid set up with the `https_port` directive, which Firefox connects to using a PAC URI like [this](https://gist.github.com/Cauterite/2291768e4f8dedc9d0cbb01cfb2157d9). It creates a secure tunnel between your browser and the proxy server without a VPN; encryption is applied even for non-HTTPS requests.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I mean creating a SOCKS5 tunnel from terminal to remote server (i.e my VPS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOCKS doesn't add any additional encryption by default. If your traffic is already encrypted then it will stay that way. While a VPN can encrypt everything leaving your machine, such as DNS.

SOCKS also does not protect against traffic analysis

I know you didn't ask benefits, but to help balance my argument for others, SOCKS can be a lot faster because of the lack of additional overhead encrypting.

Comment: Few people have fast enough network for the encryption overhead to matter. A typical desktop CPU can AES-GCM encrypt a 10 Gbit connection without breaking a sweat.